# add = (char *) wed.. what does this mean in C?

Tags: c, pointers

wed is read from scanf as

```
scanf("%x",&wed);
```

and, add is initialized  as

```
(char *) add;
add = (char *) wed;
```

what does this mean i.e. `(char *) add ??`

Comment: It's typecasting the wed to char pointer type. From your scanf format specifier it's clear that wed is hex.

Comment: maybe you meant `char * add;` instead of `(char *) add;` ?

Comment: It means nothing, your code is nonsensical and there is no context. In order for this question to be answerable, you must include all variable declarations.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
add=(char*) wed
```

is called **casting**. It converts `wed` to `char*` for this line of code, temporarily.

Now, this:

```
(char *) add;
```

is also a cast, covnerting `add` to `char *` temporarily, and then it discards the result.

Comment: What difference does it make when we use `()` of course it binds tighter than `*` but char pointer and pointer to char are both the same things.

Comment: Parenthses are used for typecasting @0decimal0, if I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your changing one variable's type to another type.  In this case, your changing wed to a char pointer.  It's called casting.  And a char pointer stores the address a char.  So in your case

```
add=(char *) wed;
```

wed is now a char pointer and stores an address for a char and add is equal to that address

http://www.improgrammer.net/type-casting-c-language/

Answer (score 0):

Here, add is of (char*) type which means it can store the address of the character
means it can store integer value at which address character is stored.

Now,

```
add=(char*) wed
```

which means you are converting to this integer(wed) to the character pointer means it will now point to a character at the address which you assigned it.